# Select-Object Expression as a string

Tags: string, powershell

If I type out my Powershell select-object expression like below:

```
$csvdata | Select-Object @{expression={$_.1}; label='first'}
```

I receive desired output:

```
first
-
mike
john
```

But if I store the expression as a string first and then call that string as the expression to select-object:

```
$tstexp = "@{expression={`$_.1}; label='first'}"
$csvdata | Select-Object $tstexp
```

The output doesn't evaluate correctly and is used instead as the object name.

```
@{expression={$_.1}; label='first'} 
-------------------------------
```

Is it possible to pass select-object an expression list as a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass it as a `[Hashtable]`:

```powershell
$tstexp = @{expression={$_.1}; label='first'}
$csvdata | Select-Object $tstexp
```

(just remove the quotes).

If it *must* be a string (I can only imagine that you are reading/generating it from outside your script), then you could evaluate it as a script block:

```powershell
# Create the string
$tstexp = "@{expression={$_.1}; label='first'}"

# Convert to script block
$tstblock = [scriptblock]::Create($tstexp)

# Execute script block
$tstval = & $tstblock

# $tstval now contains the hashtable

$csvdata | Select-Object $tstval
```

### Edit

If you must use a string, it's easier to use `Invoke-Expression` as Jeroen Mostert's answer explains (but of course, avoid the string if possible).

Comment: Excellent description of a flexible solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `Invoke-Expression`:

```
$csvdata | select-object (Invoke-Expression $tstexp)
```

Comment: This will work too but it is not good practice, briantist shows the right way

Comment: @Paul: why is constructing and evaluating a script block superior to `Invoke-Expression`? (I can see why not having it as a string at all is superior.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert that is basically the reason. Your method uses his string and requires an additional function call which would not be needed if the variable had been initialized as a Hashtable in the first place

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the clarification -- I just wanted to confirm that *if* you need to evaluate a string, there is not some reason I was unaware of to use a script block in favor of `Invoke-Expression`. Obviously, evaluating code at runtime is an icky practice that should be avoided, but that's where the question went.

Comment: Nope if you want to evaluate a String `Invoke-Expression` is the way to go

Comment: FWIW, I agree, using `Invoke-Expression` is easier if the string must be evaluated; I just forgot to include it in my answer. +1

Comment: @briantist: if you change your answer, I'll delete mine. No need to keep all this around.

Comment: I actually think it's good to have this here. No reason you shouldn't get credit for it.

Comment: @briantist: as you wish -- I'd rather have one clear answer for future visitors than credit, but I can't force you. :-)